# Listing Called procs in tcl

Tags: python-2.7, function, unix, tcl, proc-sql

Is there any way to list out all **user defined proc calls** in a Tcl file. ?

I have a TCL file, I want to list out all procs that has been called by that file.

Regards
keerthan

Comment: Execution traces can do that sort of thing with a little help. The main tricky bit is deciding on which commands to attach the traces to, and that depends on your exact use case.

Answer (score 2):

To get a message when a *specific* command is called, we can use an [`enter` execution trace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/trace.htm#M9):

```
trace add execution $theCommand enter {apply {{call op} {
    puts "Called [lindex $call 0]"
}}
```

To select which command to attach that trace to, we can use various approaches. The easiest is if you can identify a namespace whose procedures you want to attach to:

```
foreach p [info procs ::theNamespace::*] {
    trace add execution $p enter {apply {{call op} {
        puts "Called [lindex $call 0]"
    }}
}
```

You can also attach it to every procedure created when a particular file is sourced. This is a bit more complex:

```
# Need to keep this script fragment so we can remove it again after the source
set tracer {apply {{proccall args} {
    set cmd [uplevel 1 [list namespace origin [lindex $proccall 1]]]
    trace add execution $cmd enter {apply {{call args} {
        puts "Called [lindex $call 0]"
    }}
}}

trace add execution ::proc leave $tracer
source /the/script.tcl
trace remove execution ::proc leave $tracer
```

You can get pretty complicated this way (and be aware that it also can affect procedures created by the loading of packages by the script; you can stop that, but it's a lot more work). Just attaching to all procedures that are currently in a namespace is simpler.

Comment: Be aware that execution traces can have significant performance impacts.